# Minted Linenos not working after using RecustomVerbatimEnvironment

Tags: verbatim, minted

Currently I am trying to work with the minted package. My aim is to have a code snippet with the numbering for each line, which is centered in a figure.

My top level configuration looks like following:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full, fontsize=12pt, twoside=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{linenos=true}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minted}{javascript}
    let Parser = require('rss-parser');
    let parser = new Parser();
    \end{minted}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Minted package looses numbering]

The good thing is that it is centered in the document but the bad thing is that the numbering is missing.

If i comment out following line i get the numbering but the code is not centered anymore.

```
%\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}
```

Result looks like following then:
[image]

So is there any way how i can achieve both options? Centered and numbered?
Hopefully someone has an answer! :)

Comment: Don't show only snippets but a complete document that can be compiled and tested.

Comment: I Changed it! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that BVerbatim can be numbered in the standard way, but you could try this

```
\documentclass[parskip=full, fontsize=12pt, twoside=false]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{linenos=true}
\newcommand\mynumberformat{\def\FancyVerbFormatLine##1{{\theFancyVerbLine} ##1}}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}
{formatcom=\mynumberformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minted}{javascript}
    let Parser = require('rss-parser');
    let parser = new Parser();
    \end{minted}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Oh I see you found the solution, thanks.

Comment: The definition of `\theFancyVerbLine` is `\def\theFancyVerbLine{\rmfamily\tiny\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}` and you can guess what the problem was.

Comment: @egreg grumpf. Who makes such definitions? I think I will complain ...

Comment: What would the definition look like, if it was better or even perfect? Is there just a `\space` missing at the end or what is the issue?

Comment: @thymaro an additional pair of braces is missing, as it is it implicitly assumes that the \rmfamily has no side effects.